# Can we call Java web services from stored procedure?

Tags: java, web-services, stored-procedures

I have a web application which sends data to two different databases (One oracle OLTP  db and another one is mainframe-db2). I have access to the Oracle db but don't have access to Mainframe DB. Through web-services we are sending data to both of the databases.

I have been asked to create one stored procedure, to directly insert data in these db's without entering data from the web application.( Everytime entering data from front end is very tedious as for testing purpose sometimes it requies huge amount of data, so to mitigate the time I need to directly insert data in both the db).

I have made one procedure which inserts data in the oracle db, but as I said , I dont have access to mainframe db. So , i am unable to run my SP on mainframe db.

Can anyone suggest, is it possible if I can call the web-service directly in my SP so that whenever I pass the parameters, it will insert the data in both db's. ( Already there is a web-service which is doing it whenever end user enter data from front end).

Comment: you may try to look at https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws-10g

Comment: Its bit complex to understand..could you please explain if possible.

Comment: I have not tried this myself; perhaps try to contact your Oracle administrator to see if you have UTL_DBWS configured. Also, looking on the internet for UTL_DBWS brings up other references, maybe these would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks John, I got my answer on below link:http://www.sqlquery.com/dbm0415.htm